# Implementing the "more" Unix utility command

Tags: unix, utility

i am trying to implement the `more` command.  I want to learn that how can I understand if there is a pipe.  For example, if I type from the shell

```
cat file1 file2 | more
```

how can I handle that inside the implementation of more?

And is the implementation of `more` available as open source?

Actually i could not succeed from reading stdin.I've managed doing more file.txt but not cat file | more..

i think i should first read from user and put a buffer than print the buffer. my code contains:

```
if(argc == 1)
{
  fgets(line, 255, 0);
   printf("%s", line);
}
```

but it gives error.

Comment: Grab the source package from a Linux distribution. On Fedora, for example, `more` is part of `util-linux-ng`

Comment: Note that you don't need to distinguish between a pipe `command | more` and simple input redirection `more < file`; in either case, the `more` command simply reads from its `stdin`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more syntax is

```
more [options] [file_name]
```

If you don't provide a file name, the **more** command gets input from *stdin*; you can provide this input (via *stdin*) using a pipe, for example:

```
cat file.txt | more
```

This sends the output of the cat command to **more**. This is the same as doing:

```
more file.txt
```

You don't need to specifically know if there is a pipe or not; you just need to check if a filename was passed as argument to **more**. If so, the input is considered to be the contents of the file. If not, the input is considered to originate from *stdin*.

As for the source code, some google searching will take you a long way. Here is some old source code from FreeBSD:

http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/stable/2.0.5/usr.bin/more/

Or more recente source from the Ubuntu repositories:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~vcs-imports/util-linux-ng/trunk/files/head:/text-utils/

Answer (score 0):

suggest u first check the argc whether equal 1, if equal 1 ,you shoule use the stdin as your inpout file handle, so your program can handle the situation as cat file.txt | more