# where can I find source code for "more" command?

Tags: c, macos, unix

It's have wasted 1 day time of my life to search the source code for "more" command from website, such as GNU website. But I cannot find it.

In addition, when I input "man more" command in MAC terminal, it shows LESS(1), why?

Comment: See [Implementing the “more” Unix utility command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854267/implementing-the-more-unix-utility-command)

Comment: Because sometimes more is less.

Answer (score 2):

It is "less" command that provides "more" in linux. Both of them are located in "util-linux" package. You can download source from link below:

[util-linux v2.28](ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.28/)